# Run a PHP function every 30 minutes from 9AM to 7PM without using cron

Tags: php

I have a web server running on a mobile device that sends sms using API hosted on the same mobile device.
I want to run a PHP function every 30 minutes from 9AM to 7PM every day without using cron or any other hosted service.

Currently I have following code

```
function sleep_until($target_time, $min_sleep = 0) {
    $time_now = time();

    $time_to_target = $target_time - $time_now;

    // If we've already reached the target time, that's fine
    if ( $time_to_target <= $min_sleep )
    {
        // If required, sleep for a bit anyway
        sleep( $min_sleep );
    }
    else
    {
        // Sleep for the number of seconds until the target time
        sleep( $time_to_target );
    }
}

$finished = FALSE;
while ( ! $finished ) {
    $min_secs_per_loop = 1800;
    $min_pause_between_loops = 1200;

    $minimum_start_of_next_loop = time() + $min_secs_per_loop;

    # DO STUFF THAT MAY OR MAY NOT TAKE VERY LONG

    sleep_until( $minimum_start_of_next_loop, $min_pause_between_loops );

    # update $finished when required

}
```

How can I run my while loop every day from 9AM to 7PM ?

Note: As I mentioned that web server is running on a mobile device, there is no internet connectivity and no crontab is available there.

Comment: It won't help you with your issue, but it's called a "CRON", not "corn" ^^

Comment: a) it's called cron, not corn. b) *why* don't you want to use it? *that* is exactly what cron was made for.

Comment: sorry it was typo

Comment: still, the question remains **why** you don't want to use cron. the most straightforward way would be to setup a cronjob every 30 minutes and check in your script if you currently are in the requested timespan.

Comment: If you are looking for a mechanism to execute some code in a periodic manner at specific points in time, then it is `cron` you are looking for. If you insist on an alternative, then you simply insist on a drop in replacement which does not change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd primarily look for a third party replacement for `cron`, which you could install on this device. It will save you a lot of headaches, as simulating this via scripts can be troublesome.

Failing that, you'll need to write a controller-script, which calls the script in question. This controller script needs to have the `max_execution_time` set to `0`, run an infinite main loop, sleep for 1 hour, and check the time to see if it's within the parameters.
Basically something like this:

```
set_time_limit (0);

while (true) {
    $hour = date ('H');

    if ($hour >= 19 && $hour < 9) {
        // Calculate the difference between now and next time to run.
        $diff = time_in_seconds ();
        sleep ($diff);
    }

    exec ($command);

    // Find the number of seconds until the next whole hour.
    $sleep = next_hour ();
    sleep ($sleep);
}
```

Note that this is untested, but should give you a basis to start from.